# Is it possible to show the last line first?

Tags: sql, ssms

I want see quickly how much lines the results have AND the Datasets. Is it possible to sort the first column of the results panel? 3,2,1...

[image]

**Like this:**

[image]

Comment: The 1, 2, 3 is not a part of the result, its part of the grid that holds the results. It will always count from 1. What do you really want to do? If you want to know the number of lines use `COUNT(1)`, or check the Messages tab of the results.

Comment: The results panel line should start with 3.

Comment: You shouldn't store the same values in different formats in separate columns. It will lead do data inconsistency sooner or later.

Comment: Look to the pic above. This is what I mean.

Comment: Show us your original SELECT.

Comment: @Mail what you want is not possible

Comment: check the pic above. The first column.

Comment: The results panel will never start with line 3. SSMS simply doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
ORDER BY Datum_Datetime ASC
```

---

If you want a column that goes from 3 to 1 you could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Datum_Datetime ASC) COL1, * 
  FROM table
) X
ORDER BY COL1 DESC
```

Comment: No, please check the question again. This is not the answer for my question

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: please check the line number column in my both pics.

Comment: I don't understand -- line 1 will always be line 1 no matter the order.